# Pyspark increase all dataframe values by 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to increase all values in dataframe by 1 except for one column which is the ID column.

Example:

[image]

Results:

[image]

This is what I have so far but it gets a bit long when I have a lot of columns to do (e.g. 50).

```py
df_add = df.select(
  'Id',
  (df['col_a'] + 1).alias('col_a'),
  ..
  ..
)
```

Is there a more pythonic way of achieving the same results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT (based on @Daniel comment): 
You can directly use the [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

for column in plus_one_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(column, col(column) + lit(1))
```

PREVIOUS ANSWER :

Adding "1" to columns is a columnar operation which can be better suited for a [pandas_udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

plus_one_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x != "Id"]

for column in plus_one_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(column, plus_one(col(column)))
```

This will work much faster than the row-wise operations. You can also refer to [Introducing Pandas UDF for PySpark - Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)

Comment: Oh wow I completely forgot about using it with withColumn function. Really a noob mistake on my part. Thank you!

Comment: This approach is not a good solution. Quoting after the linked article:

> Computing v + 1 is a simple example for demonstrating differences between row-at-a-time UDFs and scalar Pandas UDFs. Note that built-in column operators can perform much faster in this scenario.

Other answers that use ```lit``` will have better performance (and are much simpler)

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my answer. I understand adding with `lit` will work better. Now it's a complete answer so you can upvote it as well :P

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of columns, you can use the below one-liner,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,col

df.select('Id', *[(col(i) + lit(1)) for i in df.columns if i != 'Id']).toDF(*df.columns).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| Id|col_a|col_b|col_c|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    4|   21|    6|
|  5|    6|    1|    1|
|  6|   10|    2|    1|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=withcolumn#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) method and then iterate over the columns as follows:

```
df_add = df

for column in ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"]:
    df_add = df_add.withColumn(column, expr(f"{column} +1").cast("integer"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pyspark.sql.functions.lit` to add values to columns
Ex:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
df = spark.sql("""select 1 as test""")
df.show()

# +----+
# |test|
# +----+
# |   1|
# +----+



df_add = df.select(
  'test',
  (df['test'] + psf.lit(1)).alias('col_a'),
)
df_add.show()


# +----+-----+
# |test|col_a|
# +----+-----+
# |   1|    2|
# +----+-----+

###
# If you want to do it for all columns then:
###
list_of_columns = ["col1", "col2", ...]

df_add = df.select(
  [(df[col] + psf.lit(1)).alias(col) for col in list_of_columns]
)
df_add.show()
```